# editText.getText().toString()--can't run in android

Tags: android

This is my first post on this platform, if I have done wrong, please forgive me.
These codes can run in eclipse without error, when the app run on the phone and clicked the button, the app exited with “Unfortunately，*** has stopped”. Firstly, I thought my phone is not compatible with the program, so I used the emulator and got the same result.

This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

  private Button button;
  private EditText editText;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text_layout);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test_button);
    editText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v){
      switch (v.getId()){
      case R.id.test_button:
            String inputText = editText.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, inputText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break;
      default:
          break;
      }
  }
```

}

`String inputText = editText.getText().toString()`
replaced by  `String inputText = hello` , that would be run on the phone successfully with "hello" when clicked hte button.
Thank you for helping me solve this problem

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/test_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"/>

<EditText
    android:name="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Type something here"
    android:maxLines="2"
    />
```

Comment: NullPointerException, most likely. Add the logcat, please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Also, [edit] your question to include `text_layout.xml`, or at least make sure that is the layout you want to use for your Activity

Comment: Have you checked that editText is not null?

Comment: add logcat and text_layout.xml

Comment: editText.getText().toString() does not return NPE, at the most an empty string

Comment: Make sure your EditText ID is correct (R.id.edit_text)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: my layouts are right, if I changed "String inputText " into a certain value, it could run on the device successfully. I thought the error is null point, but i don't konw why it can't run on the device, it's  just  simple code

Comment: @Nilesh Singh ,This is the error--`String inputText = editText.getText().toString();`I just run it on android studio successfully with the same code,and other people also can run .The problem must be with my configuration.